# Unable to SSH/Ping but can FTP/Connect to Apache

Tags: ubuntu, networking, connection

I've gone away for a couple of days and left my machine running at home. I was doing some stuff on it over ssh just before I left and it was working fine. I got to the hotel and connected to the wifi, the first thing I did was try and SSH into my server, only putty gave me a "Connection Refused" error. Thinking this was odd, I visited the URL on chrome, and the website works fine. Next I tried `ping`ing the server but I keep on getting timeouts.
Getting desperate at this point I ftp'd in over FileZilla - seamless.

`tracert` tells me that the packet reaches `109.159.253.86` ok and then timeouts from there - IP lookup tells me that that appears to be some kind of BT distribution center (I'm on BT at home - maybe BT are blocking the port or something?)

Using the windows `telnet` command I seem to confirm my suspicions that for whatever reason, port 22 is blocked. Ports 80 and 21 (Apache and FTP respectively) will connect albeit with bad protocol errors, however with port 22 again I get `connection refused`

This isn't the first time I've `SSH`'d into this machine from outside of my local network and I haven't had any problems before, the only difference is I'm in the middle of nowhere and thus I'm using the slow slow hotel wifi but usually I use 4G from my phone's personal hotspot, althought I don't see why that would make

For the next couple of days at least, I'm going to be constrained to fixes I can do over non-root FTP. I had an idea to maybe shift SSH operation over to another, more obscure port which I have open for a game server but I would need root-mode FTP and some way to restart the SSH service, any help would be appreciated

**tl;dr**

- `FTP` and Apache work
- `ping` and `SSH` DONT work
- I can connect to ports 80 and 21
- I cannot connect to port 22
- I don't have physical access to my machine

Answer (score 1):

It's almost certainly going to be restrictions on the hotel network or upstream. If you haven't got a usable phone signal you may not be able to do much. If you could get to somewhere with a less restrictive policy you may be able to make changes but again it could be chance. Your best option in that case would probably be to open SSH on port 443 if you're not using HTTPS as that is unlikely to be blocked.